# Unable to update app with same application ID and signing key

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, app-update

I have created two android apps that look the same. One was built using XML a few years ago, which I named app **A**. I also created a signing key for it to generate a signed build. The other one, app **B**, was built using Compose and I created it a few months ago.

Now, I would like to update app **A** with the Compose version, but I encountered an issue. Both projects have the same application ID, and I am using the same signing key for app **B**. I am able to generate a signed build for app **B**, but when I try to update the app, I receive an error message saying "`Package 'com.test.test' signatures do not match the previously installed version,`" and the device displays "`Something went wrong. App not installed.`"

Can anyone provide some assistance on how to resolve this issue? I would greatly appreciate any help.